# Count the number of lines in similarly structured text files in a folder and sum the counts

Tags: python, function, count

Thank you for all your helps on Friday. Sorry for maybe my simple questions. as I am a beginner in Python, at times I wld face some questions which are easy for more expert people but I try to improve myself.

I am going to clarify my previous question more detail. I have some text files, with your guidance ,I am able to count the lines of these text files. i would like to create a new text file as an output that in each line of this new file I have the name of the input file with the number of the lines with space and the last line of this file contain the sum of the line numbers. For instance I have some files as : points1.txt, points2.txt and points3.txt. The output file wld be :

point1  144798
point2  100000
point3  258627
sum     503425

The code I have is:

import os
folder = 'E:/MLS_HFT/TEST/Stuttgart_2009_pointclouds/'

```
def total_lines():

    count_line = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        infilename = os.path.join(folder,filename)
        if not os.path.isfile(infilename): continue
        infile= open(infilename, 'r')

        for lines in infile:
            i+=1

        outfile = ["%s " %i]
        return i
        outfile = ["%s " %i]
        outfile.write("\n".join(output))
        outfile.close()
        return outfile

        total_lines (infile,i)
        count_line = count_line + i

        output = ["%s  %s" %(item.strip() ,count_line) for item in outfile]
    outfile.write("\n".join(output))
```

I wld be thankful to have your guidance.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: do you mean count the number of entries and the sum of the entries?

Comment: I found the len function and tried it but it did not work

Comment: well,each of my files include pointclouds, so each line represent one point and I need to have the total number of points in each file and sum them

Comment: "too big" in the sense? how big in terms of memory?

Comment: it is about 915.766 kb

Comment: 915.766 kb is not a huge file at all!!!!

Comment: but when my code running reaches to this file, it gives 'memory error'

Comment: You've been asking the same question in different ways http://stackoverflow.com/q/16104711/1948860 !!! Make up your mind!!!

Comment: well, first I though I can solve this problem in MATLAB but unfortunately it did not work that is why I wld continue in python

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the total count of the number of lines in each file:

```
>>> import fileinput
>>> i = 0 # default value 
>>> for line in fileinput.input(files=('test.txt', 'test2.txt')):
        i += 1


>>> i
20
```

This can be simplified to:

```
sum(1 for line in fileinput.input(files=('test.txt', 'test2.txt'))
```

If you want single files, and you have to add them up as well, just use this in a function:

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    sum(1 for line in f)
```

Comment: sorry i donot get how this code work? where I define the root of the whole files to be read)

Comment: `sum (1 for line in...)` for either the fileinput or single file approach

Comment: @marimm In that case you want `glob.glob('/root/')` or whatever your path name is, to give you a list of files in that directory

Comment: @JonClements sorry not sure why I didn't do that before!

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of lines in a file, open it and read the lines like this:

```
fid = open('your input filename', 'r')
lines = fid.readlines()
nLines = len(lines)
```

You could then put the above in a loop that opens each of your files and sums all the nLines values to calculate a total.

EDIT:

Loop over the files like this:

```
infiles = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', ... , 'fileN.txt' ]
totalLines = 0

# Loop over array of files
for filename in infiles:
    # Open file:
    fid = open(filename, 'r')

    # Read lines and get length of returned array (array of lines):
    lines = fid.readlines()
    nLines = len(lines)
    totalLines += nLines   # Sum with total lines

    # Close the file
    fid.close()

# Show total:
print "Total lines from all files: " + totalLines
```

Comment: thank you for your help. wld u plz guide me how to put it into loop?

Comment: @mari mm: See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

```
def Total_Lines():    
    Open_File = open(File_Name,'U').read()
    Last_Line = Open_File.count('\n')
    print Last_Line
```

To count no of lines in a file

for multiple files

```
import glob

def Total_Lines(path):
    Count_Line = 0
    a = glob.glob(path+'\*')
    for i in a:
        print i
        Open_File = open(i,'U').read()
        Last_Line = Open_File.count('\n')
        print Last_Line
        Count_Line = Count_Line+Last_Line
    print Count_Line

Total_Lines(r"F:\stack")
```

Comment: thx, I tried ur code and it works nicely. may I ask how can I now make a function out of that for all the files in one folder?

Comment: please find the edited answer

Comment: thank you very much. sorry in the above code, where I have to define the route that the files are stored?

Comment: in the function call `Total_Lines(r"F:\stack")` "F:\stack" is the path where your files resides

Comment: i have tried ur code, it works for most of files. just there is one file which too big (915.766.kb) and it gives memory error, what can I do about it?+

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file structure is like as follows and the header in each file is 'points'

```
file1.txt     file2.txt    file3.txt

points        points       points
23            43           12
34            32           45
45            21           99
56                         100
                           123
```

The code could be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd # pandas is powerful
import glob # finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern 
import os
file_count_and_sum = []
os.chdir("E:/Pointfiles") # the folder where your text files are
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    file_count_and_sum.append([file,len(data['points'].values),sum(data['points'].value        s)])
print file_count_and_sum
```

Your output would print the filename, count & sum like this;

```
[['file1.txt', 4, 158], ['file2.txt', 3, 96], ['file3.txt', 5, 379]]
```

EDIT:
In that case will this work?

```
count = 0  
for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
   data = pd.read_csv(file)
   count = count + len(data['points'].values)
print count
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help.Well,I think we need to change the code the above code a bit. in ur example each line represent different value while in my files the number of lines represent the number of points, so if I have the number of line in each file, I need to sum them up after counting for each file

Comment: Check the Edit, does that work for you?

Comment: sorry just to be in a safe side, I should put the above code in a function? or how to make it general?

Comment: why would you need a function? What is your primary objective?

Comment: maybe I ask in this way, I wld like to save this code and apply it in different cases, so should not it be as a function?

Comment: check @user20044033 's answer. That should help.

Comment: i have tried ur code, it works for most of files. just there is one file which too big (915.766.kb) and it gives memory error, what can I do about it?