# Count the number of lines in text files in a folder and sum the number of the total lines using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text, file-io, count

I would like to read some text files which are in one folder in MATLAB, count the number of lines in each file and finally sum up these numbers. I would be thankful if somebody guide me how to do it in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2):

To get all the text file names use `dir(*.txt)` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html

To count all the lines see this answer: [Is there a way in Matlab to determine the number of lines in a file without looping through each line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176519/is-there-a-way-in-matlab-to-determine-the-number-of-lines-in-a-file-without-loop)

Answer (score 2):

Matlab is really not suited for that. The underlying OS usually is much better at that, so, use a system call.

Rephrasing my original answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12176519/) (I've learned a few new tricks since then :)

```
if (isunix) %# Linux, mac    
    [~, result] = system('wc -l *');    
    numLines = cellfun(@str2double, regexp(result, '([0-9]+) total', 'tokens'))

elseif (ispc) %# Windows       
    [~, result] = system('find /v /c "&*fake&*" *.*');    
    numLines = sum(str2double( regexp(result, '[0-9]+', 'match') ))

else %# Some smaller OS
    error('Unsupported operating system.');

end
```

Note that this will work fine, except

- if you're on Linux/max and have a file called `total` in the current directory :)
- the Windows version sometimes miscounts some files by 1 or 2 lines, I don't know why...

I'm pretty sure there is a cleaner one-line-solution to parse the linux result string; the current mess is due to `regexp(..., 'tokens')` returning a *cell of cells* which is pretty inconvenient for the current context (to be honest, I haven't found many contexts where it *was* convenient yet), so this must be worked-around by `cellfun`.

But oh well, it reckon it should do the trick in most circumstances.

Comment: reading the help of `find /?`, I think the reason it would miscount is if the "fake" string thing occurs in the file..

Comment: You could always get a port of `wc` on Windows: Cygwin, MSYS/MinGW, [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm), [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/)..

Comment: @Amro: True, but I wanted a solution that works without having to install any external tools.

Comment: @Amro: ah, well that might be true :) silly me